# Is there a reason C# doesn't support short-hand, null-conditional checking in logical evaluations?

Tags: c#, null, boolean, logical-operators

I'm often finding myself writing code that checks for `null` prior to checking a property for a value. The simplest form of this would be:

```
if (someInstance != null && someInstance.SomeBooleanProperty)
```

Is there a reason we can't use the null-conditional operator (`?.`) to simplify that check if the property following it is a boolean like this?

```
if (someInstance?.SomeBooleanProperty)
```

The above example won't compile because it evaluates to `null`, not to `true` or `false`, hence you get an error saying there's no implicit cast available for `bool?` to `bool`.

We could always cast, or directly check for a value, such as:

```
if (someInstance?.SomeBooleanProperty == false)
```

That works fine, and in all honesty, it's not exactly that much extra code. Just, in my opninion here, with all of the simplifications C# has introduced over the years, I can't help but wonder if there is a reason we still can't utilize a shorthand null conditional like this?

Comment: You can raise a proposal in [C# language repository](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang)

Comment: Does the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) allow what you want?

Comment: And you can always use something like `someInstance?.SomeBooleanProperty ?? false`

Comment: You answered yourself. `?.` evaluates to `bool?`, but in C# an `if` statement expects a `bool`.

Comment: @Magnetron I don't believe that's the answer to my question. Microsoft can write the language to supply an operator that returns `bool` when utilized in a conditional evaluation, I'm sure of that.

Comment: Casting from `bool?` to `bool` is a narrowing conversion, information would be lost. c# made the decision very early in the design of the type system to make all narrowing conversions explicit.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman but at compile time is the evaluation truly a `bool?`? I understand that the compiler sets it up that way, but couldn't the compiler evaluate if it should set the resulting type to `bool?` or `bool` based on whether or not it's in a logical evaluation? Ideally a conversion wouldn't even be taking place here.

Comment: This is, at it's core, exactly what an `if` statement is doing when checking a `bool` vs an `int` anyways. We're allowed to say `if (x)` so long as `x` is a `bool`, but if `x` is an `int` then it's a compilation error.

Comment: `if(...)` requires a `bool`. `Something?.Something` is a `bool?`. So you must convert the result to bool somehow, while defining what happens with `default(bool?)` (not exactly null, but close enough). `if (x == true)`, `if (x ?? false)`, `if(x.GetValueOrDefault())`, ....

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I understand all of that and I believe we are miscommunicating to be honest. I'm more of concerned with the concept of introducing short hand for `bool?` in logical evaluations. In essence, allow the use of `if (someObject?.SomeProperty)` so long as `SomeProperty` is a `bool` type. If `someObject` is `null` then `SomeProperty` can neither be true or false so we know the answer to the logical evaluation. If the conditional is looking for a `true` evaluation then the answer is `false`, and `true` if the conditional is looking for a `false` value such as `if (!someObject?.X)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the inherent problem with just using a `?.` alone is what does the condition evaluate to when `someInstance` is null.  This is why the compiler complains and why you need the null check condition and the non null boolean evaluation. The `someInstance?.SomeBooleanProperty ?? false` would satisfy both conditions. `?.` alone cannot / shoudn't infer this logic.

Comment: This is technically the answer so I must deliver the check here because I specifically asked about the `null-conditional`, in reality I'm truly curious why it's not an already defined operator (separate from `?`); let's say the operator is `!?.` for example, is there a reason we couldn't create such an operator to be utilized for true or false evaluations? Such as `&&` where if the first condition isn't met, the second isn't evaluated at all and the whole thing resolves as false? Probably rambling at this point lol sorry, great answer!

Comment: probably because the behavior of an `!?.` would potentially be different depending on what it was applied to, depending on whether or not the value was `null` or not.  this is discussed a bit more here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/271875/378018 in that one scenario `?.` returns an exception, another returns an empty string.  if there were an `!?.` where you force unwrap a nullable, that is to say you take the literal value of what should be returned, this could lead to some fairly inconsistent an unintended behavior because of the way `Nullable` is implemented in .net imo.